# What will be Supernova SN 2014J's peak brightness?

Tags: amateur-observing, supernova

1. What is the expected maximum apparent magnitude of supernova SN 2014J?
2. When will it attain peak brightness?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this website](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/home/Bright-Supernova-in-M82-241477661.html) the peak visible magnitude will be about 10.5 around February 2nd.
Earlier estimates had been a little brighter around the same date.

Answer (score 2):

The [AAVSO data](http://www.aavso.org/lcg/plot?auid=000-BLG-310&starname=PSN+J09554214%2B6940260&lastdays=20&start=2456674&obscode_symbol=2&obstotals=yes&calendar=calendar&grid=on&visual=on&r=on&fainterthan=on&bband=on&v=on&pointsize=1&width=800&height=450) seems to indicate that it might have already peaked, at around 10.5 (visual).  The infrared is quite a bit brighter, partly because it penetrates dust better.

Sky and Telescope says it peaked on Jan 31.

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect, we now know that the peak brightness was indeed 10.5 during the first week of February, 2014:

http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/observing-news/supernova-in-m82-passes-its-peak/